# Why is the Integral of $\sin^2(x)$ negative where $x<0$?

Tags: integration

I'm having a tough time understanding how the integral of $\sin^2(x)$ is negative for $x<0$ when $\sin^2(x) > 0$ for all values of $x$. If the integral is the area between $\sin^2(x)$ and the $x$-axis, how is it ever negative?

[image: sin^2(x)]

[image: integral of sin^2(x)]

Comment: The integral from where to where? The integral from $0$ to $x$ is negative when $x\lt 0$ because you count the net signed area with a minus sign when you measure from right to left.

Comment: "you count the net signed area with a minus sign when you measure from right to left" explains it. Thanks you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with $\sin$, rather with the definition of an integral. The *indefinite* integral of $f(x)$ is written $\int f(x)dx = F(x)+C$, where $F$ is the antiderivative of $f$ and $C$ is a constant.

In your example, WolframAlpha writes $\int \sin^2(t)dt = \frac{1}{2}(x-\sin(x)\cos(x))+C$. In this case $F(0)=0$, and presumably when WolframAlpha shows you the the area plot as a function of $x$, it's actually computing $\int_0^x\sin^2(x)dx$, which is negative when $x<0$ since integrals are signed, e.g. $\int_0^x=-\int_{x}^{0}$.

Comment: Since $\sin^2t$ is even, we can also write $\int_0^x\sin^2tdt=-\int_x^0\sin^2tdt=-\int_0^{-x}\sin^2tdt$.